# Select Existing SpreadSheet in Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an existing spreadsheet(named as 'abc')that i want to activate. I have written codes to open the spreadsheet on the server, but i do not know how to work on this opened spreadsheet such as editing the content. Please advice me how to work on this opened spreadsheet.

I do not need the physical spreadsheet to be opened for viewing. I only need to use codes to further edit the content inside after i opened my existing spreadsheet.

Below are the code:

```
var student_sheet=SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFilesByName('abc').next())
//I want to edit this 'abc' spreadsheet.
```

Comment: Your concern is quite vague. You might want to check this tutorial videos regarding [Google Sheets Scripts](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLv9Pf9aNgemv62NNC5bXLR0CzeaIj5bcw). Then check the official document for [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) to learn more on how to create, access, and modify Google Sheets files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a variable to it and then just update like you would an active spreadsheet.

```
function doSomething(){
  var yourSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("???????")// enter your spreadsheet id
  yourSpreadsheet.getRange("A1").setValue("boom"); // sets value in the spreadsheet
  yourSpreadsheet.getRange("B2").clearContent();//deletes values.
}
```

Comment: @PGSystemTester I think the comment from Cooper was directed more towards OP, piggybacking off of your answer in order to show OP where they need to focus on learning. I don't think it was directed at you. :)

Comment: @LauraDye this is stackoverflow, Cooper and I didn't end up posting here every day due to our excessive charisma or social etiquette. Knowing this, it's probably not hard to understand how I might be overly sensitive to someone who says you don't know `setvalues` (!!)  Those are fightin' words on SO.  (Thanks).

Comment: @Cooper, you're fine.

Comment: A fight among SO folks sounds like a perfect cure for insomnia!  I think I'm just in a bad mood today. This guy irked me and I went off on him (by SO standards). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659131/find-a-certain-word-in-a-string-in-column-b-and-then-copy-it-to-the-left-cell#68659131